# How to correctly call Postgres Function from entity framework core?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a function i need to call from Postgres, This is what i have so far:

```
var s1 = new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("_date", NpgsqlDbType.Date)
{
  Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
  Value = DateTime.Now.Date
};

var command = await _context.AggregateBalances.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * from get_aggregate_balance(@s1)", s1).ToListAsync();
```

When i try this i am getting this exception:

[image]

This is the output from pgAdmin:

[image]

To Map this result I created this model/dbset:

```
public class SPGetAggregateBalance
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}

public DbSet<SPGetAggregateBalance> AggregateBalances { get; set; }
```

Why "s1" is a column? and why it does not exist?

Comment: Please post text instead of images where possible, eg your exception stack trace. It looks like full table value support will be completed in EF Core 5, including db functions that return IQueryable. eg https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22829

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change your code using

```
var s1=DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

var command = await _context.SPGetAggregateBalances.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM  get_aggregate_balance({s1})")
```

Add add to you EF context :

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<SPGetAggregateBalance>(e =>
            {
                e.HasNoKey();
            });
```